# Read ES index into PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I want to read documents from an elasticsearch index using PySpark. I am trying to create a Spark dataframe.

```
df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .options(**es_conf_read) \
    .load(index_name)

df.show()
```

It results in the error: `security_exception: no permissions for [indices:admin/shards/search_shards, indices:data/read/search] and User XXX`. I read these privileges are for cross-cluster access, but I am working with only one cluster. https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/old/0.9.0/docs/security/cross-cluster-search/

If I access the same index with the same user via CURL, it works. On the other hand, if I try to read only the schema using PySpark, this also works: `spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").options(**es_conf_read).load(index_name).schema`

What is the right way to read an ES index into a PySpark dataframe?

Comment: Could you be sure your real index name matches with what your `index_name` variable value is?

Comment: yes, "curl -X GET host/index_name/_search" with the same index works fine

Comment: This error could be just when you try to reach some indices with a user without permission to reach those indices. So, you mean that you are using the same user and the same index that you are using with spark and curl requests? And the curl is working, but somehow, the spark could not. Both services use the Rest API of Elasticsearch and should act the same.

Comment: Exactly. With the same user and index, Curl works, Spark doesn't.